# My app's widget is gone

Tags: android, android-appwidget

**(please!!Can any one help me  )':  )**
Hi

i am developing a digital clock widget:

Herr is my code:

First on Enabled and on Receive overrides:

```
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    PendingIntent anIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent("upp"),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmMgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,System.currentTimeMillis(),1000, anIntent);
} 
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("upp")){
        ComponentName componentName =new ComponentName(context,getClass().getName());
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager=AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        int[] appWidgetIds=appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(componentName);
        onUpdate(context,appWidgetManager,appWidgetIds);
    }
}
```

and on update:

```
Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
```

and then inside of onUpdate first i have used the Time method to get the Hour and minute as string :

```
    onEnabled(context);
Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
today.setToNow();

int hour = today.hour;
String hh = Integer.toString(hour);

int minute = today.minute;
String mm = ":" + Integer.toString(minute);
```

and then i have showed those two strings inside of two image views with bitmap:

```
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView1, getFontBitmap(context, hh, Color.WHITE, 70));

        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView2, getFontBitmap1(context, mm, Color.WHITE, 70));

        ComponentName componentName =new ComponentName(context,getClass().getName());
        int[] appWidgetId=appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(componentName);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
```

my problem here is that when i add this widget to home screen there is no layout i mean my clock is gone but when i delete the on Receive override i can see my widget but it doesn't update ?
Thanks in advance